# How to transfer a leica microscope lif file to a python numpy array?

Tags: python, imagej

I am working with confocal microscope which generates image files in .lif format.

People use to open these files using ImageJ and then convert them into  TIFF files.

I want to be able to manipulate this files using python, but I want to skip having to depend on ImageJ.

My question is: Is there a way to open/ read lif leica files using python?

thank you

Comment: Not a full answer, but google points me to [`python-bioformats`](https://ilovesymposia.com/2014/08/10/read-microscopy-images-to-numpy-arrays-with-python-bioformats/)

Comment: I didn't know about bioformats. Thank you. I explored their website and yes, they support .lif and other 140 other microscope files.